# Magento 2 - jQuery validation custom error message

Tags: magento2, jquery, form-validation

I have the following input that requires validation. When the `remote` method is failed, it displays an error message `Please fix this field.`. How can I customize this message?

```
<input type="text" data-validate="{required:true, email:true, remote:'/bonus-point/transfer/validateRecipientEmail'}" class="input-text" title="Recipient Email" value="" id="recipient_email" name="recipient_email" aria-required="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to return a custom error message in json

```
public function execute() {
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
    if (strlen($message) < 3) { 
        $resultJson->setData('Message too short'); // error
    } else {
        $resultJson->setData('true'); // success
    }
    return $resultJson;
}
```